# Getting column-wise means and standard deviations for positive and negative values separately in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I can get column-wise means and standard deviations (sample) of a dataframe as follows:

```
means <- apply(df , 2, mean)
sdevs <- apply(df , 2, sd)
```

However, my dataframe contains positive and negative values and I need to get means and standard deviation for positive and negative values separately

**Example Input:**

```
COL1 COL2
1    1
2    1
3    1
-1   -1
-5   -1
-9   -1
```

**Example Output:**

```
positive_means = [2,1]
positive_sdevs = [1,0]
negative_means = [-5,-1]
negative_sdevs = [4,0]
```

I do not want to build a for loop because my data frame contain too much values and columns.
Thanks.

Comment: `for` loops are not bad per se. It is bad, or let us say improvable, if loops are used although vectorized functions exist, see `?colMeans`. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this creating a group for positive and negative values and then summarise with `dplyr` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% mutate(group=ifelse(COL1>0&COL2>0,'Pos','Neg')) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% summarise_all(list('mean'=mean,'sd'=sd))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  group COL1_mean COL2_mean COL1_sd COL2_sd
  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Neg          -5        -1       4       0
2 Pos           2         1       1       0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(COL1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, -1L, -5L, -9L), COL2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Another option can be using `apply()` and `rowSums()`:

```
#Code1
as.data.frame(apply(df[rowSums(df)>0,],2,function(x) {data.frame(Mean=mean(x),SD=sd(x))}))
```

Output:

```
  COL1.Mean COL1.SD COL2.Mean COL2.SD
1         2       1         1       0

#Code2
as.data.frame(apply(df[!rowSums(df)>0,],2,function(x) {data.frame(Mean=mean(x),SD=sd(x))}))
```

Output:

```
  COL1.Mean COL1.SD COL2.Mean COL2.SD
1        -5       4        -1       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another base R option to add to Duck's excellent answer:

```r
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) c(mean_pos = mean(x[x > 0]), 
                                       mean_neg = mean(x[x <= 0]),
                                       sd_pos   = sd(x[x > 0 ]), 
                                       sd_neg   = sd(x[x <= 0]))))
#>          COL1 COL2
#> mean_pos    2    1
#> mean_neg   -5   -1
#> sd_pos      1    0
#> sd_neg      4    0
```